# yarn logs + blk_xxxxxx_xxxxxx does not exist or is not under Construction

Tags: linux, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

We have spark cluster with the following details ( all machines are linux redhat machines )

```
2 name-node machines 
2 resource-manager machines 
8 data-node machines ( HDFS file-system)
```

We are running running spark streaming application

From the yarn logs we can see the following errors , example:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_xxxxxxxx -log_files ALL


---2019-11-08T10:12:20.040 ERROR [][][] [org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus] Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): BP-484874736-172.2.45.23-8478399929292:blk_1081495827_7755233 does not exist or is not under Construction
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkUCBlock(FSNamesystem.java:6721)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.updateBlockForPipeline(FSNamesystem.java:6789)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.updateBlockForPipeline(NameNodeRpcServer.java:931)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.updateBlockForPipeline(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:979)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2351)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2347)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2347)
```

we can see that - `8478399929292:-blk_1081495827_7755233` does not exist or is not under Construction

but what could be the reasons that yarn complain about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to yarn documentation

```
yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID> -am ALL
```

Will be more appropriated